# Sending Arabic SMS using JSMPP

Tags: java, encoding, intellij-idea, jsmpp

I have created an application which retrieves SMS from database and send it over SMPP using JSMPP. When I run it from IDE (Intellij Idea) it delivers the SMS correctly to cell phone but when I create Jar of it and than run it as a window service than the SMS is not correctly encoded. My question is, are there any certain JVM parameters that I should pass to while creating Jar ?

Comment: Locale or charset. If the problem is encoding, why don't you post the code for encoding?

Comment: because its working fine as for as I run the code from IDE but not working when I run the Jar.

Comment: Then the code is not fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I must run the Jar by passing an encoding parameter to JVM.

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar myJarName.jar
```